# How to pull 3 random records per category in Presto SQL?

Tags: sql, presto

I have the following table:

```
category_id  name
    5         rob
    5         james
    5         kobert
    5         ken
    4         jef
    3         rok
```

I want to write a query that gives random 3 names per each category.

Possible output for example can be:

```
category_id  name
    5         rob
    5         james
    5         ken
    4         jef
    3         rok
```

I know it should be something like:

```
SELECT category_id, name
FROM(
    SELECT category_id, name, RANDOM() Over (Partition By category_id) rn
    FROM dataset )
WHERE rn<=3
```

but I can't find the proper syntax to do this.
It gives me

> Not a window function: random

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT category_id, name
FROM (SELECT category_id, name,
             row_number() Over (Partition By category_id order by random()) as seqnum
      FROM dataset
     )
WHERE seqnum <= 3;
```

That is, the `random()` goes in the `order by`.

Comment: didn't know I can do order by random. I thought order by can be done only on table columns. Is there somewhere to read about all other options in order by?

Comment: @HaloKu . . . I think any scalar expression can be used, although Presto may not allow subqueries in the `order by` for a window function.

Comment: should it be order by random() ?